# Unable to load file via pickle

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, pickle

I am using an example program from [github](https://github.com/debayanmitra1993-data/Blindness-Detection-Diabetic-Retinopathy-/blob/master/2_process.ipynb)  in which it has imported pickle module at the beginning. But when it is trying to open file via pickle. *Its giving an error*
I can't understand the reason of it.

```
file = open('df_train_train', 'rb')
df_train_train = pickle.load(file)
file.close()

file = open('df_train_test', 'rb')
df_train_test = pickle.load(file)
file.close()
```

screen shot of my result.

[image: Error]

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question, not as image or external link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `dump` it first, then load it. Try the following:

```
# dump df_train_train
file = open('df_train_train', 'wb')
pickle.dump(df_train_train, file)
file.close()
```

Then

```
file = open('df_train_train', 'rb')
df_train_train = pickle.load(file)
file.close()
```